# Debug Spark worker thread using IntelliJ or Get the function trace of worker

Tags: scala, debugging, intellij-idea, apache-spark

I am trying to debug a spark application using IntelliJ. 
I can debug the driver part (or till the execution is running on the driver), but once, it's moved on the worker, I am not able to debug it. 
I get the result from worker through Listener, but don't get any window to debug the worker.

I have tried the both ways. First, by running the spark application in IntelliJ IDE and then debug and second, by running the application using "spark-submit" and then using the remote debug.

I am running it locally. Below is the spark submit command:

```
spark-submit --verbose --master "local" --class "Test" target/scala-2.11/test-assembly-1.0.jar
```

I have also seen the threads mentioned in the answer of a similar [question](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Debugging-spark-java-application-td19270.html#a19284) in apache-spark users list. 
But it didn't work out for me.

I basically want to see the function trace of worker here. So if there's any way that I can  get the function trace, that will also work for me.

So could someone here suggest me anyway for debugging the worker or getting the function trace of the worker?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this link: http://danosipov.com/?p=779

Basic procedure (directly from the page, with a few additions):

1. Package your application into a jar.

sbt assembly
-or-
mvn clean package

2. Set debugging options for Java (via SPARK_JAVA_OPTS environment variable) when you submit your jar to the cluster. See the note in the comments about using suspend=y to keep the worker from starting that code without your debugger connection. Make note of the port number that you specified (here 5005).

export SPARK_JAVA_OPTS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005

3. Use spark-submit to transfer the jar to the cluster. Make sure to use the fully qualified class name and the path to your generated jar file. The heartbeat parameter increases the amount of time until the Spark driver will kill your application due to an unresponsive executor.  The default (10s for me) didn't work very well for debugging.

/path/to/spark/bin/spark-submit --class Test --master local[4] --driver-memory 4G --executor-memory 4G --conf spark.executor.heartbeatInterval=200s /path/totarget/scala-2.10/project-assembly-0.0.1.jar

4. Create a remote debug configuration in IntelliJ (Run menu -> Edit Configurations -> + -> Remote) and make sure the port number matches what you specified in the environment variable.  Give it a name, like 'Spark Debug'
5. Set your breakpoints, and then Connect the debugger (also Run menu ->  Debug 'Spark Debug').
6. Have fun!

Comment: Updating the answer one more time -- Spark returned this deprecation warning:

16/10/06 14:25:13 WARN SparkConf:
SPARK_JAVA_OPTS was detected (set to '-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005').
This is deprecated in Spark 1.0+.

Please instead use:
 - ./spark-submit with conf/spark-defaults.conf to set defaults for an application
 - ./spark-submit with --driver-java-options to set -X options for a driver
 - spark.executor.extraJavaOptions to set -X options for executors
 - SPARK_DAEMON_JAVA_OPTS to set java options for standalone daemons (master or worker)

Comment: One more comment.  The above comment is valid, but it still works.  I'm having a few subtle problems with the alternatives, so stick with the above for now.

Comment: I tried this approach, but I wasn't able to debug the worker thread. It connected me to the driver thread only which I can debug by running it directly from IntelliJ. I followed the same steps mentioned on the linked page!! 

Are you able to debug the worker thread code by following these steps??